# rails 3.1, why my coffee scripts not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I am trying to test coffee script in my rails 3.1 project, but it doesn't get executed, or generated as javascript in the application.js

I have a controller `Page`, here is the pages.js.coffee:

```
test = (input) ->
  alert input

test 'hello'
```

but that alert never get executed at http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages, 
in fact, the application.js is just empty!

here is the GemFile in case it would help:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'devise', '1.4.8'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'

#gem 'nested_form', :git => 'git://github.com/fxposter/nested_form.git'

gem "simple_form"

gem 'kaminari'

gem 'foreigner'

gem "cocoon"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem "jquery-rails"

gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'haml'
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

**EDIT**

I have added those gems also and installed them, but, the coffee script is not executed

```
gem 'therubyracer'


gem 'coffee-script-source'
gem 'json'
gem 'execjs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Having "coffee-rails" in your :assets group should be enough.  Older versions had "coffee-script" in the :assets group.

Second: Where are you keeping your `*.js.coffee` files?  You need to make sure they are in an "assets" folder some place.  Start with `app/assets/javascripts`.  If they aren't in your assets folder, they won't make it into the asset pipeline.

If you are doing that already, consider starting a new project and use the default configuration.  It should work without any trouble.  Compare the working project against the non-working project.

If all else fails, is it possible for you to share your project with us on GitHub?

Comment: thanks for your good idea! I have created a new project, and noticed the difference, in my application.js, the "//= require_tree ." is simply missing!

Comment: ^^ that was it for me as well.  forgot to add those requirements to the top of application.js after converting to 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config/application.rb, you should find a section like this:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 #Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

end

I suspect you are not precompiling assets on deploy, even though you have it set to ignore the assets gems.